# IndexError: list index out of range, хотя такой ошибки не должно возникнуть

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, случайные-числа

Делаю программу, которая рандомно генерирует слово из массива:

```py
from random import randint

print("Начало")
while True:
    print(["rare", "rare", "rare" "superrare", "superrare", "superrare", "epic", "epic", "mythic", "mythic", "legendary"][randint(0, 10)])
```

Вот что ввыводит:

```
Начало
superrare
mythic
epic
legendary
mythic
mythic
mythic
mythic
superrare
mythic
rare
```

и ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sysroot/home/user/PycharmProject/Lunx/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(["rare", "rare", "rare" "superrare", "superrare", "superrare", "epic", "epic", "mythic", "mythic", "legendary"][randint(0, 10)])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

И у меня возникает вопрос: почему?

Всего элементов в массиве: 11

`randint(0, 10)` генерирует случайное число от **0** до **10**, что превращается в индекс массива

Что не так?

`Python 3.8` (`PyCharm Community Edition`)

Comment: Я уже исправил это поставив вместо `randint(0, 10)` `randint(0, 9)`, но почему оно не работало с 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я заметил следующее:

```
from random import randint
print("Начало")
list1 = ["rare", "rare", "rare" "superrare", "superrare", "superrare", "epic", "epic", "mythic", "mythic", "legendary"]
print(len(list1))
print(list1)
while True:
    print(list1[randint(0, 10)])
```

Вывод следующий:

```
['rare', 'rare', 'raresuperrare', 'superrare', 'superrare', 'epic', 'epic', 'myt
hic', 'mythic', 'legendary']
```

Обратите внимание на 3-й (по индексу 2) элемент списка. Python склеил две строки 
`"rare" "superrare"`
Поэтому элементов в массиве не 11, а 10. Надеюсь мой ответ помог

Comment: не обязательно считать длину, можно так: ```print(random.choice(list))```

Comment: @Акмаль но проблема в том что автор при создании списка допустил ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Я понял. У меня допущена ошибка в `["rare", "rare", "rare" "superrare", "superrare", "superrare", "epic", "epic", "mythic", "mythic", "legendary"]` и там есть `"rare" "superrare"`. Также можно использовать `random.choice`, но я просто не хотел его импортировать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1224221/400096 лучше принять этот ответ

Answer (score 1):

потому что всего у вас в массиве 11 элементов

когда вы используете randint(0, 11) то получаете числа от 0 до 11 **включительно**

а у вас значения от `[0]` до `[10]` (это как раз 11 элементов), в когда вдруг выпадает 11 и выполняется обращение к `[11]` - тут и происходит выход за диапазон

поэтому надо делать так:

```
random.randint(0, len(arr) - 1)
```

а на самом деле для вашей цели есть специальный метод choice

```
random.choice(arr)
```

который все сделает сам - выберет случайно один из элементов массива

Comment: у автора опечатка `"rare" "superrare"` отсутствует запятая, и из-за этого в массиве 10 элементов, а не только 11. Если бы там стояла бы запятая то ошибок бы не возникало

Answer (score 1):

вот лучший вариант:

```py
import random

words = ["rare", "rare", "rare" "superrare", "superrare", "superrare", "epic", "epic", "mythic", "mythic", "legendary"]

while True:
    print(random.choice(words))
```